# macOS crashes when watching fullscreen video in Chrome

Tags: crash, macos

I'm not sure this is a macOS bug, a Chrome bug or something else but my macOS crashes when I'm watching fullscreen video in Chrome. By crashing I mean that I'm suddenly logged out from the system and all apps are closed. This happens very quickly in about a second, like I'm watching a video and suddenly I'm on a screen where you choose an account to log in macOS.

This happened at least 5-6 times since I installed macOS. I've never noticed same behavior on previous OS X versions.

Has anyone experienced the same? Is there any solution?

P.S. I'm testing this in other browsers and will update the question with results.

Comment: Exact same question. When I was beta testing Sierra, I thought it was a bug, but now I have the stable version, and I still have the problem. I t only happens in Google Chrome - Full screen.